# Ternary operator within a JSON or alternatives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Json, of which I want to put a condition, if a parameter is sent, that the attribute "params" is present, otherwise it should not be present in the $http request. How can I do it? I would like to do it in an optimal way to save code.

```
    function getWebService(param){

         $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://www.reddit.com/.json",
            params:param
            //params:param?param:''
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log("good")
        },function(response) {
        console.log("bad")
        });
 }

 getWebService({"limit":2}); //atribute params should exist 
 getWebService();  //atribute params should'nt exist
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrvmxwmk/

Comment: You simply don't need a ternary, use it as it is. Should work :)

Comment: I think the current code looks good. The extra attribute with null value wouldn't have any effect.